# Why is my .exe file not working on other computers?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, exe

I made an executable file of a python program I made.
It imports selenium , chromedriver , requests and os modules.
When I run the .exe file after entering the required inputs in the console, the website my program points to doesn't not opens.And the console closes immediately

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import requests
import os


class YoutubeBot():
    def __init__(self,url_list,path):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="F:/Environments/project1_env/lib/site-packages/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
        self.url_list= url_list
        self.path = path


    def download(self):
        print("Starting Download.")
        sleep(2)
        c = 0
        for self.url in self.url_list:


            self.driver.get("https://en.savefrom.net/15/")

            sleep(6)
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sf_url"]').send_keys(self.url)
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sf_submit"]').click()
            sleep(15)
            #self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sf_result"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]').click()
            #elf.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sf_result"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a[1]').click()
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sf_result"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a').click()
            #exit()
            if c<5:
                self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[2])
                sleep(2)
                self.driver.close()
                sleep(2)
                self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])
            c =c +1


    def startfile(self):
        print('Opening File')
        sleep(2)

        os.startfile('{}'.format(self.path))

url_list = input().split(" ")
path = input("Path of the folder where the files have to be downloaded. \n")
my_bot = YoutubeBot(url_list,path)
my_bot.download()
my_bot.startfile()
```

I used cx_Freeze to convert it into a .exe file. Code for it is below:

```
        from cx_Freeze import setup , Executable
    setup(name = 'YoutubeBot',
            version ='0.2',
            description = 'Bot',
            executables = [Executable("F:\projects\\YoutubeBot\\youtube_bot.py")])
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Environments\project1_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Environments\project1_env\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 40, in run
  File "F:\Environments\project1_env\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 37, in run
  File "F:\projects\YoutubeBot\youtube_bot.py", line 48, in <module>
  File "F:\projects\YoutubeBot\youtube_bot.py", line 9, in __init__
  File "F:\Environments\project1_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
  File "F:\Environments\project1_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: can you provide more information. How did you compile the exe, what is the error message when running on another machine?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your chromedriver needs to match the version of chorme you have installed. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads if the other PC doesn't have the same version of chrome that you have on the PC you built it on then I could see that causing issues.

Comment: I have added changes to my question. I hope it answers your questions @bmcculley

Comment: On Windows, if you run the .exe from the command line instead of double-clicking the .exe, the console should stay open so you can read the error.

Comment: How can i take care of this issue, considering that i can't control the versions of chrome on other computers?? . @Phillyclause89

Comment: I have no idea to be honest.  I don't even know if that is the true root cause of your issue. If it is then you might need to build multiple .exe s for each version of chrome you want to support, or maybe there is a way to detect what chome version the user has and make sure the program points to the correct driver for it?  My experience with web automation is very limited and I've never tried to make an .exe out of a selenium script before, so I'm really not going to be much help here.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective.

Comment: I have added the error as text @JörgWMittag

Comment: _'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH._ Seems like it can't find chrome. Is it on the path?  You may have to update PATH manually to reference the exe.

Comment: It is in path on my computer. But how to solve this path issue , when i use the same .exe file on other computers . @tdelaney

Comment: @LokeshJain Great question! I think you bundle a copy with your exe and put it where you can find it. Here is the home page for chromedriver (there is a download link in there)  https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: Yes it worked, tysm :) !